# jruby gem installation error or any gem: "ERROR: While executing gem ... (Errno::ENOENT)"

Tags: java, jruby, jrubyonrails, solaris-10

When trying to install any jruby gems, I get the following error.

```
$ jruby -S gem install rails
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::ENOENT)
    No such file or directory -
```

Unfortunately no directory or file listed in the error message.  When I searched for this error it usually ended up being a permissions issue with a specific file or directory, but in this case none is listed.

Any help or direction would be much appreciated.

Jruby: 1.6.7.2
OS: Solaris 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I've found that there's a [bug in JRuby 1.6.7 and 1.6.6](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-6494) where gem installation fails on Solaris.  Currently gem installation on Solaris only works with Jruby 1.6.5.1 and earlier.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a system install of JRUby, your issue may be your need root access to install gems. If that is the case, try installing the gem with `sudo`:

```
sudo jruby -S gem install rails
```

I would suggest using [RVM](https://rvm.io/) to [install JRuby](https://rvm.io/interpreters/jruby/). It takes a lot of the guess work out of the installation.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have sudo access.  I took a look at RVM, but Solaris 10 lacks some of the prerequisites.

Comment: Do you happen to have any links that goes into details about how to do a user or multi-user install?  Maybe that will help lead me in the right direction.

Comment: Also, this doesn't appear to be a permissions issue.  I went through the same procedure on a different server where I do have root access, and I still have the same problem.

Comment: The install docs for RVM talks about single vs multi user installs: https://rvm.io/rvm/install/#explained